# Errors in (German language) alert from an .asp form

Tags: forms, vbscript, asp-classic

There is a confirmation message that we are having a problem with

[image: confirmation message]

The code is currently

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>")
Response.Write("alert('Vielen Dank für Ihre Anfrage zu BruxZir Zirkonoxid. Wir haben Ihren Wunsch nach weiterer Information erhalten und werden Sie innerhalb der kommenden f&uuml;nf Arbeitstage kontaktieren. Bitte halten Sie sich auf dem Laufenden über unsere wachsende Liste an autorisierten BruxZir Laboratorien.');")
Response.Write("window.location.replace('index.aspx');")    
Response.Write("</script>")
```

As you can see even when the German HTML entity `&uuml;` is added, it does not show up properly. The actual entity shows up. But when we enter `ü` the character does not show up as intended.

The HTML form uses what I think might be VBScript in the .asp form. I am not sure sure this is not my primary language. How can I address this?

```
<form action="send.asp" method="post" name="Form1" id="Form1">
```

EDIT:

This now shows what I have in my send.asp file after the first answer on the question.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
function TestCaptcha(byval valSession, byval valCaptcha)
valSession = Session(valSession)
Session(valSession) = vbNullString

valCaptcha = LCase(valCaptcha)
valSession = LCase(valSession)

if valSession = vbNullString then                       
    TestCaptcha = false
else
    if (StrComp(valSession,valCaptcha) = 0) then    
        Call ProcessContact
    else
        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>")
        Response.Write("alert('Sie haben einen falschen Code eingegeben. Bitte versuchen Sie einen anderen Code.');")
        Response.Write("history.go(-1);")
        Response.Write("</script>")
        Response.Flush
    end if
end if
end function
%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<%
Sub ProcessContact
Response.Buffer = true  
dim gFName, gLName,  gEmail
<!-- more code below -->
```

And this is the new alert which seems fine. But did I structure my code well here?

[image: new alert]

Comment: Yes, I think the structure is oke, personally I would indent the code inside the function a bit to the right. The codepage is at top off the page, that's were it should be. The content-type is in the <head> that's were it should be. Here is nice set of characters to test any internalization case: áäÇçéčëíďńóöçÖöÚü This string also contains unicode only characters (the č ď and a third which I can't rembember).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing two essentials lines in your source:

```
 <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

This is a duo. It tells the ASP VBscript engine to work internally with 2 bytes character strings and, if you use `response.write`, to actually convert strings to UTF-8. The second line tells the browser to anticipate receiving UTF-8.

Do not use the `chr` / `asc` functions; instead, use the `chrw` and `ascw` functions. 
And make sure to use an editor which is capable of saving your source files in UTF-8.

That should fix your internationalization problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
'The LCID property specifies how dates, times, and currencies are formatted
'German - Germany
Response.LCID = 1031

'The CodePage property specifies, how strings are encoded
'65001 utf-8
Response.CodePage = 65001

'The Charset property appends the name of a character-set
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
```

Comment: I am curious to know more about this. I updated my code above and wondering how your suggestion would fit in, thanks.